# Bash, how to print out that files are the same when using cmp

Tags: bash, cmp

`cmp file1 file2` does nothing when the files are the same. So how do I print out that files are the same in shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exit status of `cpm` is zero if the files are identical, and non-zero otherwise. Thus, you can use something like

```
cmp file1 file2 && echo "Files are identical"
```

If you want to save the exit status, you can use something like the following instead:

```
cmp file1 file2
status=$?
if [[ $status = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Files are the same"
else
    echo "Files are different"
fi
```

Comment: Can I assign the exit status of cpm to some variable in bash?

Comment: `var=$?`; just after `cmp <file1> <file2>`

Comment: this will also work `if (cmp file1 file2); then echo "same"; else echo "not"; fi`

Comment: @AvinashRaj The parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: Shorthand for if/then/else without a variable:
`cmp file1 file2 && echo "Files are identical" || echo "Files are different"`

Comment: A dangerous shorthand if used improperly; this works because `echo` always exits 0, but if the command following `&&` fails, the command following `||` is executed as well. `a && { b || true; } || c` is more correct (but uglier).

Answer (score 2):

Use the exit status code of `cmp`. Exit codes of 0 mean they're the same:

```
$ cmp file1 file2; echo $?
0
```

In a script you can do something like this:

```
cmp file1 file2 && echo "same"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display the result, you can also use `diff -q -s file1 file2`:

- The `-q` option (AKA `--brief`) makes `diff` work similarly to `cmp`, so that it only checks whether the files are different or identical, without identifying the changes (Note: I don't know if there's a performance difference between this and `cmp`).
- The `-s` option (AKA `--report-identical-files`) makes it display a "Files file1 and file2 are identical" message rather than giving no output. When the files differ, a "Files file1 and file2 differ" message is shown either way (assuming `-q` is used).

[Source](https://ss64.com/bash/diff.html)